# i cant get twilio's node module to get available phone numbers

Tags: node.js, api, twilio

i'v taken the following code straight from the twilio api explorer

```
// Twilio Credentials 
var accountSid = 'A***************************b25'; 
var authToken = 'f5a***************************e2'; 


//require the Twilio module and create a REST client 
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); 

client.availablePhoneNumbers('US').local.get({          
    excludeAllAddressRequired: "false", 
    excludeLocalAddressRequired: "false", 
    excludeForeignAddressRequired: "false" 
}, function(err, data) { 
    data.incomingPhoneNumbers.forEach(function(number) { 
     console.log(number.PhoneNumber); 
    }); 
});
```

but i get the following TypeError resulting in a 500 response from sails.js

```
client.availablePhoneNumbers(...).local.get is not a function.
```

i went into the http://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/index.html to view the library directly and found the following works but returns a 404

```
client.availablePhoneNumbers.get(country).local.list(function(err,data){console.log(err,data)})

[Error: [404] Unable to fetch record.
{"code": 20404, "message": "The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/US/AvailablePhoneNumbers/A***************************b25/Local.json was not found", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404", "status": 404}]
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I can only apologise, through our investigation of your reports we've found a number of issues in our documentation relating to this API call. Could you drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com, we'd love to send you something for drawing this to our attention.

Anyway, with the issues you found. The API explorer code was incorrect as it calls `data.incomingPhoneNumbers` in the callback, where that should be `data.availablePhoneNumbers`. You also need to call `number.phoneNumber` with a lower case "p" in the callback. Try this code instead:

```
// Twilio Credentials 
var accountSid = 'A***************************b25'; 
var authToken = 'f5a***************************e2'; 

//require the Twilio module and create a REST client 
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); 

client.availablePhoneNumbers('US').local.get({          
    excludeAllAddressRequired: "false", 
    excludeLocalAddressRequired: "false", 
    excludeForeignAddressRequired: "false" 
}, function(err, data) { 
    if (!err) {
        data.availablePhoneNumbers.forEach(function(number) { 
            console.log(number.phoneNumber); 
        }); 
    } else { 
        console.log("Error: ", err);
    }
});
```

I will report the errors in the API explorer code and documentation so hopefully no one else is bitten by this issue.

Let me know if this helps.

**Edit**

This seems to be a disconnect between the 3.0.0-rc1 release of the Twilio module that is not backwards compatible with the old 2.x series.

I recommend you downgrade to twilio@2.9.0 and use the code from above.

Comment: I think that was your catch not mine. but i still have a problem. the url im getting is way off what your api documentation says it should.

Comment: Are you able to run the code I supplied? Does that work for you?

Comment: Which version of the helper library are you using?

Comment: No i cant seem to work out your documentation for this. i see several ways of doing it none of which seem to work for me. but before that in the error message im getting the url returned doesnt match what your api documentation states. i was able to use postmen with this url "https://ACc**********b25:f5a******c4ce2@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACca***********b25/AvailablePhoneNumbers/US/Local" to get a correct response. but your nodejs module seemed to use "/2010-04-01/Accounts/US/AvailablePhoneNumbers/A***************************b25/Local.json"

Comment: according to npm list  twilio@3.0.0-rc1

Comment: Ah, ok, that's a new version of the lib, so the docs on the main site don't match it just yet.

Comment: Can you downgrade to twilio@2.9.0 and try again?

Comment: yep works just as expected. thanks for the help. thought i was going mad.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's sorted, I'll try to get this fixed for v3.